# Does self-answering a question increase reputation?

Tags: discussion, reputation, self-answer

Look at [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1104292/php-user?tab=answers). He is answering only his own questions. My question is: Does this increase reputation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Does it increases reputation ?

You do not get the 15 points (or the +2) for accepting your own answer on a self-answered question. However, votes still count as usual (that is +10 for an upvote, -2 for a downvote).

Other than that, there is nothing about self-answering that inherently increases reputation beyond the normal rules.

Comment: It is also a handy way to document a problem you've faced so you and others can find it later